# Como comparar esses 2 arrays dentro deste while?

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo semelhante à Forca, aonde o usuário tem que acertar a palavra escolhida pelo computador em até 8 tentativas.

A variável `mascara` é um array de caracteres que corresponde a palavra que o usuário vê na tela (que pode não mostra todas as letras) e a variável `palavraSeparada` é um array de caracteres que corresponde a palavra que o usuário deve adivinhar

Estou com dúvida no laço `while` abaixo. Como faço para verificar se o conteúdo dos dois arrays é igual?

```
while(acertou==false&&errou<8){

    for(int i=0;i<mascara.length;i++){
        System.out.print(mascara[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("");
    letraDigitada = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

    for (int i=0;i<palavraSeparada.length;i++){
        if (letraDigitada == palavraSeparada[i]){
            mascara[i]=letraDigitada;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso é pra implementar um jogo de _Mastermind_ (AKA Senha)? Qual o conteúdo de `palavraSeparada`? Qual o conteúdo esperado de `mascara`?

Comment: @LucasGoeten Tomei a liberdade de acrescentar um texto introdutório para dar mais contexto a quem estiver vendo esta questão. Caso discorde de algo ou queira acrescentar mais alguma informação, basta clicar no link de editar.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, ao invés de `acertou==false`, use `!acertou`.

Segundo, use o método `equals(char[], char[])` da classe `java.util.Arrays`.

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
while (!acertou && errou < 8) {

    for (int i = 0; i < mascara.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(mascara[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("");
    letraDigitada = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < palavraSeparada.length; i++) {
        if (letraDigitada == palavraSeparada[i]) {
            mascara[i] = letraDigitada;
        }
    }

    if (Arrays.equals(mascara, palavraSeparada)) acertou = true;
}
```

No código, ainda falta incrementar o `errou` no caso de o `if` que está dentro do `for` não entrar nenhuma vez. Isso deixo para você resolver, mas é fácil. :)